# Git pull cause file to be deleted

Tags: git, ubuntu, sh

I created a shell script which runs when my server starts.
Its goal is to pull the latest update from my remote repository:

```
#!/bin/sh
branch="production_test";
git --git-dir=/var/www/html/.git checkout -b $branch 
git --git-dir=/var/www/html/.git pull https://username:password@bitbucket.org/my/path/to/repository.git $branch
```

In order to test it I add a file named `test.file` into my local repository, committed it and pushed it to the remote repository.

At first when I rebooted my server, I thought the script did not run since in my `/var/www/html` folder nothing changed.

**BUT**, when I did `git status` It shows me the test.file is marked as deleted.

When i'm doing `git log` i see me last commit.

If I manually run my script in the server - it works perfectly.

What can cause that? Maybe `Ubuntu` has some sort of a layer to which defends file changing (i'm just shooting at the dark) ?

**UPDATE**

This is the output of a log file to which I redirected both std and stderr to:

```
fatal: A branch named 'production_test' already exists.
From https://bitbucket.org/my/path/to/repository.git
 * branch            production_test -> FETCH_HEAD
Merge made by the 'recursive' strategy.
 test.file | 0
 1 file changed, 0 insertions(+), 0 deletions(-)
 create mode 100644 test.file
fatal: A branch named 'production_test' already exists.
From https://bitbucket.org/my/path/to/repository.git
 * branch            production_test -> FETCH_HEAD
Already up-to-date.
```

This is the output of `git status` command after reboot:

```
Changes not staged for commit:
  (use "git add/rm <file>..." to update what will be committed)
  (use "git checkout -- <file>..." to discard changes in working directory)

    deleted:    test.file
```

I am able to learn from the output that the bash script ran twice probably by 2 rc.d boot commands. Yet it does not explain this behaviour.

Comment: Can you redirect output of this script in some log-file and see what have happened?

Comment: @RomanZaytsev I Added it to my question. the log looks fine.. does not explain the delete of the file..

Answer (score 0):

Ok so I got this to work with help from other answers here.
Apperantly I was missing the `--work-tree` configuration in my command line, so I just added:

`--work-tree=/var/www/html/` in my command and it worked.

Can really say I really understand what it does since i never changed anything in the work tree of my repository - but at least it works.

This is my final script:

```
#!/bin/sh


branch="production_test";

git --git-dir=/var/www/html/.git --work-tree=/var/www/html/ checkout -b $branch   
git --git-dir=/var/www/html/.git --work-tree=/var/www/html/ pull https://username:password@bitbucket.org/my/path/to/repository.git $branch
```